# Yum is not able to update on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, yum

This is the message i m getting while update yum

```
[root@n yum.repos.d]# yum update

Setting up Update Process
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/fc/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 : http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/fc/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: mysql56-community. Please verify its path and try again
```

Can any one help me how i can solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a HTTP 404. This error code means "Not found". You have an extra repository for MySQL which is outdated.
Check

```
/etc/yum.repos.d
```

for the repository which is broken and remove the .repo file. Yum update should run now.

If you really need MySQL you can check the [digitalocean HowTo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html). But MySQL Server is included in the standard CentOS6 repository. Package name is:

```
mysql-server
```

Comment: [root@n yum.repos.d]# yum remove  mysql-community.repo
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: mysql-community.repo.           I 
 tried to reveme rempo but same erro is displyaing after this message.

Comment: cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
check for MySQL repo
remove the file or move it to another directory

Comment: I could remove the .repo and update the yum successfully. Thanks for the replay.